# Sql Error:A network-related or instance-specific error while establising connection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, installation

I have developed a c# winforms application. On my developement system the application is working correctly.

I created the setup and installed the application on the test system.
On the test computer I installed 
**sql server express**

and the services of the testing computer the sql server and sql browser are running.

But when opening the application. It is showing the following error

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

connection string i have given is

```
<add name="JaithramConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=EasyCab;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

on testing computer the sql express is installed as **Use the Built in Account - local system** and instance **default instance**

Sql surface is configured to accept remote connection.with named and tcp/ip pipes.

I am Confused with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remote into the test machine, can you access the sql server via SSMS or Visual Studio or something along those lines?  Basically, are you sure the problem is with your code and not the instance of SQL on the test box?

Comment: `.\SQLExpress` doesn't look right to me - you may need to qualify the source, AFAIK: `ServerName\SQLExpress`. I'm no expert though, and the string might well be valid.

Comment: Have you tried "Data Source=." ?

Comment: Please check the file wall settings for this computer.  Even though you're using .\SQLExpress or (local)\SQLExpress it attempt to resolve the port which when closed...